# Repeatable sub forms in Cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cakephp

I'm looking into using CakePHP to build a web application.  The sticking point is that I need to be able to generate forms that contain repeatable subforms.  These subforms would consist of sets of fields with a delete button and a single add button.  Clicking the add button would add a new set of fields, while clicking any of the delete buttons would delete that single set of fields.  These buttons would use JavaScript to add and delete the subforms.

Example:
The company has a Client, and this Client has many Contacts.  The form for this situation would consist of a form to fill in the client data, and the subform would allow the user to enter in a name and email for each of the contacts.

Is anyone aware of any existing libraries for CakePHP that do this?  Alternatively, is anyone aware of a well built generic library for performing this task?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up writing a library for this.  Maybe I'll post it someday when it's of a bit higher quality than an additional Form Helper layer.

Answer (score 0):

that is a frontend issue and nothing to do with cake, its all done with javascript so something like jquery is what you would need.

something like http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/58/adding-unlimited-form-fields-with-jquery-mysql/

look at the demo found http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/2/1/

Comment: It is a front end issue, but it originates on the back end because you need to also integrate data restoration when validation fails, or when you edit an existing record.  Thus, what I'm looking for is a comprehensive library to tie everything together rather than writing custom PHP on every form to generate the fields, then separate JavaScript to perform the repeating for each sub form.